# Many template10 resizer on same page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I use template10 library on my uwp application.
I tried to put 4 resizer control on textbox on the same page.
But when i drag one, grabbers of others textboxes are also moving without the textbox.

What i want is :

- if i grab one grabber, only this grabber is supposed to move
- the others are not supposed to move together

Do you have any idea ?

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MedicalInfoGroup" Margin="0,0,0,24">

    <controls:Resizer Margin="0,0,0,24">
        <TextBox    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    MinWidth="500" MinHeight="100"
                    Text="{Binding MedicalInformationsItem.Treatment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    InputScope="Default"
                    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
        </TextBox>
    </controls:Resizer>

    <controls:Resizer Margin="0,0,0,24">
        <TextBox    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    MinWidth="500" MinHeight="100"
                    Text="{Binding MedicalInformationsItem.MedicalHistory, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    InputScope="Default"
                    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
        </TextBox>
    </controls:Resizer>

    <controls:Resizer Margin="0,0,0,24">
        <TextBox    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    MinWidth="500" MinHeight="100"
                    Text="{Binding MedicalInformationsItem.SurgicalHistory, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    InputScope="Default"
                    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
        </TextBox>
    </controls:Resizer>

    <controls:Resizer Margin="0,0,0,24">
        <TextBox    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    MinWidth="500" MinHeight="100"
                    Text="{Binding MedicalInformationsItem.Allergies, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    InputScope="Default"
                    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
        </TextBox>
    </controls:Resizer>

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the HorizontalAlignment of the Resizer to Left instead of the TextBox

```
<controls:Resizer Margin="0,0,0,24"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             MinWidth="500" MinHeight="100"
             Text="{Binding MedicalInformationsItem.Treatment, Mode=TwoWay}"
             InputScope="Default"
             IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
    </TextBox>
</controls:Resizer>
```

Comment: WOW, it works. Big thanks Shawn
Can you just explain to me what is the difference between put horizontal alignment on resizer and on textbox ?

Comment: The Resizer has a default HorizontalAlignment of Stretch. In it's content it has the triangle grip which aligns to the Right. Since the control stretches to fill the space it's given, then grip will be to the far right.
Does that make sense?